# Как подсчитать количество определенных слов на странице?

Tags: php

**Всем привет,я новичок в php и в целом в программировании и я не найду на просторах интернета
как подсчитать количество определенных слов на странице.**

**Суть такова, есть один сайт,на котором мне нужно подсчитать количество слов "Онлайн",т.к это мониторинг,затем записать в переменную и через переменную уже вывести на страницу моего сайта.**

Буду очень благодарен за вашу помощь и подсказку =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сделать GET запрос на сайт тем же curl, получить html код страницы.
2. Пользоваться встроенной в php функцией strpos до тех пор, пока не вернет false и увеличивать счетчик.